# Calling a java script class method by class name dot prototype dot method name

Tags: javascript

I need to understand the following code. Can someone please explain it.

```
var MyClass = function(){
 this.publicMethod = function(){
  console.log("I am a public method");
 }

 MyClass.prototype.foo = function(){ //Need to know how it is working.
  console.log('I am in foo');
 }

}

var myClassObject = new MyClass();
MyClass.prototype.foo(); // If I don't include the above line it throws an exception.
```

I need to know how last two statements are working?

Comment: `MyClass.prototype.foo();`  <-- makes no sense

Comment: @epascarello does MyClass.prototype.foo = function(){
  console.log('I am in foo');
 }
statement in "MyClass" make scene??

Comment: Why would you set `MyClass.prototype.foo` over and over again every  time the constructor is called?

Comment: @ozil That line is not doing what you think it is... You actually want `myClassObject.foo()` unless you are not after separate instances than you probably do not want to be using prototypes.

Comment: @torazaburo may be this is a way to call a class method without class instance just like static method in java i don't know. But if it is like this then why I need this statement "var myClassObject = new MyClass();" before method call

Comment: If you want a class method, then define it as `MyClass.foo = ...`. If you want an instance method, define `MyClass.prototype.foo` **outside** the constructor. But it makes no sense then to call it as `MyClass.prototype.foo()`, since it will have no `this` pointing to the instance.

Comment: @torazaburo can you give some example code how can i call "foo" method without "myClassObject".

Comment: I'm confused. `foo` is an instance method. That means it's called on an instance. Methods on prototypes are instance methods. What does it mean to call an instance method not on an instance? What would you hope to accomplish by doing that? If the instance method tries to access any instance properties or other instance methods, how will it know which ones to access if it was not called on an instance?

Comment: @torazaburo In the posted code why/how "MyClass.prototype.foo()" letting me to print message on console "I am in foo".

Comment: Then you might as well just name the function `boo` and define it as `function boo() { console.log("I am in boo"); }` and call it as `boo()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67487/discussion-between-ozil-and-torazaburo).

Answer (score 1):

The issue doesn't really have anything to do with classes or prototypes.

If you don't call `var myClassObject = new MyClass();`, then `MyClass` is never executed, and the assignment `MyClass.prototype.foo = function(){}` never takes place.

Here is a simpler example:

```
var foo;

function bar() {
    foo = 42;
}

console.log(foo);
```

`foo` will be `undefined` because `bar` is never called and could not change the value of `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you define a constructor's prototype outside the constructor itself. There is no reason to do it inside the constructor as it will continually (and unnecessarily) redefine itself. Consider this pattern:

```
//data specific to the instance goes into the constructor
var Employee = function (first, last) {
   this.firstName = first;
   this.lastName = last;
}

//prototype methods defined outside constructor. Only defined once
//getFullName method will be available on any instance of an Employee called by
//'new Employee(...)'
Employee.prototype.getFullName = function () {
   return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}

var alice = new Employee("Alice", "Smith");
var bob = new Employee("Bob", "Doe");

console.log(alice.getFullName());
console.log(bob.getFullName());
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know how last two statements are working?

It's easy, coz `prototype` can add function in already created object or "class" in js.
But it's soft typo. Prototype will be fire if none specific function are present.

check this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/hu5UYKduodhUZt2GH1N5?p=preview

and now check this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Gt8v2il0Exx6g715Ir1d?p=preview

Did you see a different ??

In second example, prototype didnt work, coz MyClass have a it own "method" call `MakeAWishSecond`
but in first example MyClass don't have they own `MakeAWishSecond` "method".

If you use prototype, you can add some "methods" to all objects / "class" even on this build in core ;)

Comment: In the posted code why/how "MyClass.prototype.foo()" letting me to print message on console "I am in foo".

Comment: yes it's letting you to print message in console, coz you add this function to all MyClass object's using prototype. But u didnt need to do it in declaring a structure of class but late in use. As you see in my examples, you can add some functionality to all objects without change structure of MyClass. More information: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp